# Can relative homotopy groups be represented as relative homology groups of some Moore complex?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Daniel Kan defined a combinatorial version of the homotopy group $\pi_n(X)$ of a simplicial set $X$ as the $(n-1)$st homology of the (non-commutative) Moore complex $\tilde{G}(X)$, where $G_iX$ is essentially a free simplicial group generated by $(i+1)$-simplices with suitably chosen boundary and degeneracy operators, $\tilde{G}_n(X):=\cap_{i>0}\,\mathrm{Ker}\,\, d_i$ and $d_0: \tilde{G}_n(X)\to \tilde{G}_{n-1}(X)$ the ''boundary'' map. ([Link to the original paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970006?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents))

My question is: if $K$ is a simplicial subset of $X$, is there any simple relation between $\pi_n(X,K)$ and the homology $H_{n-1}(\tilde{G}X, N)$ where $N$ is the [normal closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_closure) of $\tilde{G}(K)$ in $\tilde{G}(X)$?

More generally, is there a "combinatorial version" of $\pi_n(X,K)$?